# Understanding operator == in Java

Tags: java, operators

The [JLS 8, chapt 15.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) specifies two concepts named `floating point equality test` and `integer equality test` as follows:

> If the promoted type of the operands is int or long, then an integer
>   equality test is performed.
>
> If the promoted type is float or double, then a floating-point
>   equality test is performed.

Where floating point's defined as follows:

> Floating-point equality testing is performed in accordance with the
>   rules of the IEEE 754 standard:

So, we can refer to IEEE 754 in order to describe behavior with floating-point equality. But what about `int`s? Where the JLS specifies how it performs integer equality test?

Comment: Do you need a quotation? The test is a trivial comparison of the bit pattern since integer representation is unique.

Comment: @Henry Yes, I do. I'm looking for a quotation. BTW, the integer representation depends if we use 1's/2's complement or signed magnitude. So, I think it's not exactly true that the integer representation is unique, because there may be two different representations of 0. Am I right?

Comment: The signed two's complement representation is specified here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`int` and all other integral types are signed two's complement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) in Java, you shouldn't worry about having two different ways of representing 0.

Since you were looking for a reference, [the JLS §4.2.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) provides one:

> If an integer operator other than a shift operator has at least one
>   operand of type long, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit
>   precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type long.
>   If the other operand is not long, it is first widened (§5.1.5) to type
>   long by numeric promotion (§5.6).
>
> Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit precision, and
>   the result of the numerical operator is of type int. If either operand
>   is not an int, it is first widened to type int by numeric promotion.